# using ObjCHiredis for ios on redis

Tags: ios, redis

I need to use Redis for my iOS app and I downloaded the the libraries from https://github.com/lp/ObjCHiredis and installed Redis on my computer. I then created a small program to see if it would work. Here is the output that I'm getting below and you can read the code at http://pastebin.com/uduB92cf .

```
2012-05-29 10:32:34.186 RedisVideo[19023:707] loaded
2012-05-29 10:32:34.262 RedisVideo[19023:707] redis created
2012-05-29 10:32:34.276 RedisVideo[19023:707] __NSCFString
2012-05-29 10:32:34.277 RedisVideo[19023:707] subscribe
2012-05-29 10:32:34.280 RedisVideo[19023:707] __NSCFString
2012-05-29 10:32:34.281 RedisVideo[19023:707] CHANNELZ
2012-05-29 10:32:34.283 RedisVideo[19023:707] __NSCFNumber
2012-05-29 10:32:34.284 RedisVideo[19023:707] 1
2012-05-29 10:32:34.290 RedisVideo[19023:707] command sent
2012-05-29 10:32:34.291 RedisVideo[19023:707] ERR only (P)SUBSCRIBE / (P)UNSUBSCRIBE / QUIT allowed in this context
2012-05-29 10:32:34.320 RedisVideo[19023:707] command sent
2012-05-29 10:32:34.321 RedisVideo[19023:707] there was a response
2012-05-29 10:32:34.323 RedisVideo[19023:707] ERR only (P)SUBSCRIBE / (P)UNSUBSCRIBE / QUIT allowed in this context
2012-05-29 10:32:34.325 RedisVideo[19023:707] command time over
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the call to subscribe to a channel in the lazy substantation method.

```
-(ObjCHiredis*) redis
{
    if(!redis)
    {
        redis = [ObjCHiredis redis:@"10.0.0.5" on:[NSNumber numberWithInt:6379] db:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
        NSLog(@"redis created");
//        [redis command:@"SUBSCRIBE CHANNELZ"];
//        id retVal =  [redis command:@"SUBSCRIBE CHANNELZ"];
//        if( [retVal isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] )
//        {
//            NSLog(@"%@",(NSString*)retVal);
//        }
//        else if( [retVal isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] )
//        {
//            for (id foo in retVal)
//            {
//                NSLog(@"%@",[foo class]);
//                if( [foo isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] )
//                {
//                    NSLog(@"%@",(NSString*)foo);
//                }
//                else if( [foo isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] )
//                {
//                    NSLog(@"%d",[(NSNumber*) foo intValue]);
//                }
//            }
//        }
    }
    return redis;
}
```